# Exporting of an object in a component in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to export css stylings written in Style.jsx to main index.js however I got an error :   Line 40:1:  Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

```
import React from 'react';

const y = new Date();
const x = y.getHours();
const Hew = "";

function Style() {
  if (x > 1 && x < 11) {

    Hew = [{
        backgroundColor: '#ED810A'
      },
      {
        marginLeft: 'auto'
      },
      {
        marginRight: 'auto'
      },
      {
        borderRadius: '50%'
      }
    ]

  };

  if (x > 12 && x < 19) {

    Hew = [{
        backgroundColor: '#16DCDE'
      },
      {
        marginLeft: 'auto'
      },
      {
        marginRight: 'auto'
      },
      {
        borderRadius: '50%'
      }
    ]

  };

  if (x >= 20 && x <= 24) {
    Hew = [{
        backgroundColor: '#2A7272'
      },
      {
        marginLeft: 'auto'
      },
      {
        marginRight: 'auto'
      },
      {
        borderRadius: '50%'
      }
    ]
  }
  
  export default Hew;
```

Style.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import App from './App'

ReactDom.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

index.js

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing bracket around the function. Also FYI, you're not calling this function, so `const Hew = ""` is always exported as-is. Consider streamlining the whole thing:

```js
function computeStyle() {
  const hour = new Date().getHours();

  // These are the same for all your styles!
  const commonStyles = [
    { marginLeft: 'auto' },
    { marginRight: 'auto' },
    { borderRadius:'50%' }
  ];

  if (hour > 1 && hour < 11) return [
    { backgroundColor: '#ED810A' },
    ...commonStyles
  ];

  if (hour > 12 && hour < 19) return [
    {backgroundColor: '#16DCDE'},
    ...commonStyles
  ];

  if (hour >= 20 && hour <= 24) return [
    {backgroundColor: '#2A7272'},
    ...commonStyles
  ];
}

export default computeStyle();
```